# How to restrict client IP address in Java Web Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ip

I need to restrict my view based on Client IP address, I have list of static IP addresses and I want to display view only to those who's ip addresses are registered in my java web application

Comment: Restriction based on IP addresses is generally not a good idea. The client can easily hide or change his IP, so it is preferable some sort of authentication to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon how you want to achieve the filtering.

1. You can use a filter, which will validate and only then forward the request to the Servlet
2. In the Servlet / Controller, you can write a check to control the redirection to a valid JSP or an error JSP
3. Load the list in the servlet context and use that to check whether or not to show the content in JSP.

If I were you, I would use a filter, that way you are not even touching the Servlet layer with that IP.

See this link to know about Servlet Filters - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

Comment: I need ip address through javascript, how can i do that?

Comment: @DanialSaeed IP Address of the client cannot be retrieved from JS because of security reasons. An option is to call a servlet which will return the IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you would like to do.

Among other things you can filter out (restrict) the view of your applications to certain IPs only by configuring the server.

How to do it depends on the server.

For example for Tomcat you would need to edit the `org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve` in the `context` (filename: `context.xml` ).
See also: 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter

- The advantage of this method is that you completely isolate the
  application development from the IP filtering. And that you can apply
  the filtering to multiple applications.
- The disadvantage would be that it is less flexible and less customizable than an application based solution.